# Doctrine ORM: Where am I going wrong with YAML to define Many to Many relationship?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, twig, silex

I'm using Silex with Doctrine ORM trying to create mappings to the database with YAML. I have a many to many relationship between the `categories` and `products` tables and wish to have categories on the owner side.
However, whenever I try to dump '$productCategories' in the twig file by

`{% for productCategories in category.productCategories %}

     <li><a href=""></a>{{ productCategories.name }}</li>

 {% endfor %}`

I receive:

> Variable "productCategories" does not exist in "category.twig"

Here is the Categories.yml file:

```
MVCStore\Entity\Category:
type: entity
table: categories
manyToMany:
    productCategories:
        targetEntity: MVCStore\Entity\Product
        inversedBy: category
        joinTable:
            name: products_categories
            joinColumns:
                products:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                categories:
                    referencedColumnName: id
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: auto
fields:
    name:
        type: string
    parent_id:
        type: integer
```

And  here is the products.yml file:

```
MVCStore\Entity\Product:
type: entity
table: products
repositoryClass: MVCStore\EntityRepository\Product
oneToMany:
    productImages:
        targetEntity: MVCStore\Entity\ProductImage
        mappedBy: product
manyToMany:
    productCategories:
        targetEntity: MVCStore\Entity\Category
        mappedBy: products
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: auto
fields:
    stock:
        type: integer
    name:
        type: string
    description:
        type: string
    featured:
        type: boolean
    price:
        type: decimal
```

If anything more is needed please ask.

Comment: Could you also include the array of variables that you pass when calling `->render()` method of `Twig`?

Comment: @Artamiel `$app->get('category/{name}', function($name) use ($app) {

    $category = $app['orm.em']->find('MVCStore\Entity\Category', $name);

    return $app['twig']->render('category.twig', array( 'category' => $category )); 
});`

Comment: Well, as you can see the only variable you send to your template is `category`, yet you are trying to access an undefined one, named `productCategories` as your error states.  Most likely, are trying to access the association from `Category` in a wrong way.

Comment: @Artamiel I did something similar before. I accessed a variable called productImages which had a oneToMany relation to products, only difference is is that productCategories is a manyToMany relation.

Comment: Could you edit your post by adding the part of the template file when you actually trying to access this association, and it should be a little bit more clear as of why you get the error?

Comment: @Artamiel Would you also like to see the mapping objects?